# how to save values from one class object to another class object

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I have two classes(Pojos) name `Soldbookdetails.java` and `Bookdetails.java`, 
what I want to do is, I have to get  data from Bookdetails table(`Soldbookdetails.java`)  and save the same  data to my Soldbookdetails table(`Soldbookdetails.java`).

**ActionClass.java**

```
private Double[] id;//With getter and setter
private Double[] quantity;  //With getter and setter
Bookdetails book=new Bookdetails();//pojos,//With getter and setter
Soldbookdetails sbook=new Soldbookdetails();//pojos,//With getter and setter 
BookdetailsDAO dao=new BookdetailsDAO(); 
SoldBooksTransactionDAO dao2=new SoldBooksTransactionDAO(); 
------------
```

(Note: *my both pojo are same only their Class name are different*)

**My problem**: I am unable to save record from `Bookdetails.java` to `Soldbookdetails.java` .(See My above `ActionClass.java` class,inside the  execute method , i have mention  the ERRROR).

After getting record by Bookid , i am unable to save the record into my `Soldbookdetails.java`.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Please don't post huge code here. Post a specific problem instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `saveSoldbooks(Soldbookdetails s)` method takes an object of `Soldbookdetails` as argument but you are passing an object of class `Bookdetails`.

The thing you can do is you can add a method that copies the attributes of an `Bookdetails` object to an `Soldbookdetails` object (without the id field). Then you should try to save the object of `Soldbookdetails` using your existing method.

Comment: Thanks Sazzadur Rahaman. This solution i know. I can do this. But i want to solve my problem as i stated above. I want to learn new thing.

Comment: If you want to save an object of Bookdetails to the table of SoldBookdetails. You have no other option to create a separate object of SoldBookdetails class and copy the attributes to it, because hibernate does not know that your Bookdetails object has all the informations to save it as soldBookdetails. You must explicitly create an object of soldBookdetails class to save it in your table for soldBookdetails (without having an id). No matter from where you gether information to create that object... :)

Comment: Can you share comment as code .. I  have little doubt how to write in code as you said **You must explicitly create an object of soldBookdetails class to save it in your table for soldBookdetails (without having an id). No matter from where you gether information to create that object.**

Comment: `SoldBookDetails sbd = new SoldBookDetails();` `sbd.setName("name")` `//set other things but dont set id if you have an object with id, hibernate dont save that object (it only updates it)` `dao.saveSoldBookDetails(sbd);`

Answer (score -1):

While keeping sold books and books in separated tables is (IMO) good perfomance issue, I think you don't need to create separated IDENTICAL classes for them.
Consider making you're class BookDetails an abstract and annotating it as [MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BookDetails{
    // fields
    // getters
    // setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="SoldBooks")
public class SoldBookDetails extends BookDetails{
    // Currently blank
}


@Entity
@Table(name="BookDetails")
public class TradingBookDetails extends BookDetails{
    // Currently blank
}
```

While currently you're classes are identical, at future you may decide to create others book types (like other table and classes for purchasing books to store or books in the way to customer) and, of course, there may appear different logic for SoldBooks and others, and in this case such 'abstraction' will simplify maintenance.

The only changes to you're saveSoldBook I currently see is to change it's argument type or provide type check in the body of the method, as long as while argument type is BookDetails, you can pass in the function any variable, derived from it - therefore, TraidingBookDetails, SoldBookDetails etc. (Changes needed depends on you're logic in this method and DAO itself).

Comment: BookDetails is the admin master table where he can edit/delete the record also. And SoldBooks table is the table where sold books record will be kept after invoice generation. Advantange: If Admin deletes/record  from BookDetails  table then it will not effect the record of SoldBooks table. Admin can easily find out his exact sales record...

Comment: You're inherited classes will just inherit persistence annotations, but they'll map to tables, specified in inherited class. For example, if BookDetails have ID and Name columns, they'll appear in SoldBookDetails details. Yes, they'll be mapped exactly as they mapped in BookDetails, but they'll refer to SoldBooks.id and SoldBooks.name respectively (as long as SoldBookDetails mapped to 'SoldBooks' table). The opportunity to delete records from BookDetails without touching same ID's in SoldBooks will stay.